# Display the counter of the product beside the cart button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I add the counter beside the cart button on my products page (not the details product page), and it would appear like in the picture bellow
Can someone tell me which plugin should I use or any other suggestion?
Thank you in advanced!

[image: A picture showing what I mean]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce Shop page: Quantity input on add to cart button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968332/woocommerce-shop-page-quantity-input-on-add-to-cart-button)

Comment: But it helps people I didn't find it easily there so I decided to share it here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display quantity input fields for simple products within your shop archive pages, you can add the following code to your active theme’s *functions.php* file.

```
/**
 * Code should be placed in your theme functions.php file.
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        $html .= '</form>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this for a project I was working on not too long ago. This does what you need and is quite easy to follow: https://gist.github.com/JeroenSormani/a3325bdbca57f59690c1#file-woocommerce-archive-page-quantity-field-php

So you simply add this to `functions.php` and refresh... You may need to do:

```
.archive .quantity {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

so it displays correctly.